# Does matplotlib support linux 64bit?

Tags: linux, 64-bit, matplotlib

I can see installation files for windows 64bit and 32bit, but the tar.gz file for linux doesn't say whether it is 64 or 32bit.

Comment: Appropriately written code will work on 32 and 64 bit systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tar.gz is likely a source package, you have to compile it yourself.

And yes, matplotlib works fine as 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

The only Linux I'm familiar with is Ubuntu.  There, `apt-get` is your friend.  You do not need to compile.  However, there are a few [steps](http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2011/08/trying-ubuntu-linux-2.html) involved, depending on what you already have on your machine.